# How to turn a dataframe index which only contains zeros into a sequential one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

So, i'm using a little bit of code a friend made me once but i'm dealing with some inconvenience: every index value is 0, as you can see in the image bellow!

I tried `df.reset_index()` and it didn't work. Is there any way to solve that or am i stuck with the zeros forever?

. [image: My index only has zeros]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work? **Edit: It wont i looked it up**

```
df = df.reindex(index=[x for x in range(len(df.index))])
```

You could also make a new DataFrame with a new index like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=[x for x in range(len(df.index))])
```

When trying .reset_index() are you assigning your dataframe variable to the result like this?

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

I often forget to do this

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I got this error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I've edited my response a few times so are you trying the latest edit? Just want to make sure. Did you try creating a new DataFrame as well?

Comment: I tried your last snippet and it worked! I just had to to drop the new index column that was created and voilà! Cheers mate!

Comment: You can automatically drop the old values by using: df.reset_index(drop=True) Glad it worked! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do would be to add a column to the dataframe, then set that new column as the index
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html